# Prefix of regular language

Tags: regular-languages

we have the following languages - $L_1 ,L_2$ .
we'll define new language:
pref$(L_1,L_2)$= {x $\in$ $\Sigma$*| $\exists$ u $\in$ $L_2$  s.t: x $\bullet$ u $\in$ $L_1$ }

can we say that:
$L_1$ ,$L_2$  $\in$ L<sub>reg</sub> $\to$ pref$(L_1,L_2)$ $\in$ L<sub>reg</sub> ?

Comment: The operation you define here is often called right quotient. This might help you finding an answer on this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because an answer can be found easily on this site or on the internet.

Comment: Crosspost with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431035/l-1-and-l-2-are-regular-and-we-have-a-new-language-textprefl-1-l-2/4431052#4431052) on MathStackExchange.